# angular.bind vs ECMAScript 5 .bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-5

Is there any advantage to using angular.bind instead of ECMAScript 5's Function.prototype.bind?

Is it just a shim to support older browsers or is there some advantage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is essentially a shim with some typechecking. `Function.prototype.bind` is an ES5 construct, so you are looking at IE9+, FF4+, etc.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/fc05f5e701f77012d54f87facb5a83d56996c7f1/src/Angular.js#L796-L814)